# Error while trying to execute Sugar database CRUD operation

Tags: android, compiler-errors

I (having mediocre developing skills) actually try to use Sugar as a database wrapper for my android project.
Therefore, I was following along the "Getting-Started-Guide" (http://satyan.github.io/sugar/getting-started.html) to get ready as soon as possible.

I created a class for my entities, called DataSet.java :

```
import com.orm.SugarRecord;

public class DataSet extends SugarRecord{
    int someData;
    double evenMoreData;

    public DataSet(Context ctx){
        super(ctx);
    }

public DataSet(Context ctx, 
        int someData, 
        long evenMoreData) {
    super(ctx);
    this.someData = someData;
    this.evenMoreData = evenMoreData;
    }
}
```

I call the class in the following way:

```
someGreatClass something;
someMoreGreatCode somemore;

DataSet dataSet = new DataSet(
            ctx,                            // Here Eclipse throws the error
            something.method(), 
            somemore.anothermethod());
DataSet.save();
```

When I try to build this and to push it onto my device, Eclipse refuses to compile and throws this error:

```
ctx cannot be resolved to a variable
```

Considering the fact that I'm relatively new to Android development, the error may be obvious and I hope to get a tip how to solve this.

P.S.: Furthermore, I don't fully get the developer's statement in the getting-started-Note:

```
Please retain one constructor with Context argument. (This constraint will be removed in subsequent release.)
```

Thank you very much!

// Edit: Did edit the class name from LocationDataSet to Data set for clarification

Comment: Did you add (or extend) the SugarApplication?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the getting-started-note tells you that you need a constructor with only a context parameter, you did this here so that's ok

```
public DataSet(Context ctx){
    super(ctx);
}
```

about

```
ctx cannot be resolved to a variable
```

I think you don't have a variable called ctx, I don't know if you're familiar with android context? (basically a context is a service or an activity), if you're using this code in an activity or a service, just use the 'this' keyword and not the ctx variable

The code you provide doesn't really show what you're doing, but you showed us the code from 'DataSet', but the error happens with a LocationDataSet? And you're calling save on DataSet? 
The save method must be called on an object, not a class.

Also don't forget that sugar needs the special application class in the manifest

UPDATE with example:

Your dataset class (the sugarrecord) should look like this, that's ok in your code as far as I can see

```
public class DataSet extends SugarRecord<DataSet>{

private String someData;

public DataSet(Context c){
    super(c);
}

    public DataSet(Context c, String someData){
    super(c);
    this.someData = someData;
}

}
```

An activity that uses the record should look like this

```
public class SomeActivity extends Activity {

    public void someMethodThatUsesDataSet(){
        // Create a dataset object with some data you want the save and a context
        // The context we use here is 'this', this is the current instance of SomeActivity, 
        // you absolutely need this, I think this is what you're doing wrong, 
        // you can't use ctx here because that's not a known variable at this point
        DataSet example = new DataSet(this, "data you want to save");

        // Tell Sugar to save this record in the database
        example.save();
    }
}
```

Comment: LocationDataSet is the original name of the class in my code, I forgot it to change it to DataSet.

Comment: What do you mean by using "this"? If I just replace "ctx" with "this", Eclipse immediatly throws the error "The constructor DataSet(ShowLocationActivity, long, long, double, double, float, float, String, boolean, int, int, String, int) is undefined" (if I use it when I call the class)

Comment: If your ShowLocationActivity is extending Activity, it is a valid context. Are you sure that the types of the other arguments of the constructor are correct?

Comment: The error keeps present even when I just copy that "Getting-Started" example from the website. I simply don't get it why it's throwing that ctx-error...

Comment: Can you give some more info about your ctx variable? Where does it come from? (declaration, initialisation)

Comment: I just copied the code from the developer's website. I think ctx does come from DataSet.java: Context ctx